# Sets of arrays of different length (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

E.g., when processing the set of plane contours:
each one consists of N nodes and may be described by the matrix N*2
(x, y coordinates of every node).
In MATLAB it may be done with cell array Contours{}.
Every element corresponds to one contour and storeы the array of coordinates of the nodes.

What is the recommended object (data type) in Python for such set of contours ?

Comment: You probably need to make your own `Contour` class, python is not a mathematical language. However, you can look into 3rd-party packages such as [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/contour_api.html#matplotlib.contour.ContourSet).

Comment: rassar, thank you for the interesting idea.

Comment: It seems list of arrays is the requested object.
Thanks.